# puppet like dsl in ruby

Tags: ruby, dsl

I'm implementing an internal DSL using ruby. I provide a command line tool to execute DSL scripts written in files (much like [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/)). At first I was going to use load() to run the scripts, thing is, I want to be able to pass some context before I execute the script. I was hoping I could read a script in text form and treat it as a block and then have that block executed with some given context. Is something like this possible?

Or how are such things generally achieved? It can be done for sure because puppet does it. But before I can dig through its code base, I'm trying here.

Also, are there any nice small examples of internal DSL implementations I could look at?

Answer (score 1):

Check following links please, a series of DSL articles.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-cb04046/index.html
http://deadprogrammersociety.blogspot.de/2006/11/ruby-domain-specific-languages-basics.html
http://deadprogrammersociety.blogspot.de/2006/11/ruby-domain-specific-languages-basics_08.html
http://deadprogrammersociety.blogspot.de/2006/11/ruby-domain-specific-languages-basics_19.html
http://deadprogrammersociety.blogspot.de/2006/11/ruby-domain-specific-languages-basics_27.html

Comment: Apart from that, you should know the **hierarchy of class and metaclass** in Ruby, and definitely understand the difference between **class_eval** and **instance_eval**.

Comment: If you plan to spend more time on that, you'd better read the book [**Metaprogramming Ruby: Program Like the Ruby Pros**](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby)